# separate the values of columns

Tags: python, dataframe

I have the following data frame and I want to separate it based on commas

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "column0": ["xx, aa", "xx, aa"],
        "column1": ["yy","yy"],
        "column2": ["cc, xx", "cc, xx"]})
```

Expected outcome:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "column0": ["xx"],
        "column1": ["aa"],
        "column2": ["xx"],
        "column3": ["aa"],
        "column4": ["yy"],
        "column5": ["yy"],
        "column6": ["cc"],
        "column7": ["xx"],
        "column8": ["cc"],
        "column9": ["xx"]})
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You'd probably need to prepare your data for that as you have generated key names and string processing. For example, you can do this:

```py
d = {"column0": ["xx, aa"],
     "column1": ["yy"],
     "column2": ["cc, xx"]}
d2 = {}
keynum = 0
for key, value in d.items():
    for item in value[0].split(", "):
        d2[f"column{keynum}"] = item
        keynum += 1
```

### Update

You can add another loop for this case.

```py
d = {"column0": ["xx, aa", "xx, aa"],
     "column1": ["yy","yy"],
     "column2": ["cc, xx", "cc, xx"]}
d2 = {}
keynum = 0
for key, value in d.items():
    for list_item in value:
        for item in list_item.split(", "):
            d2[f"column{keynum}"] = item
            keynum += 1
```

Comment: how to use this code when i have multiple rows?

Comment: @xavi, provide a more complete test case to get more complete answers.